# GitVersionTask v4 with an MSBuild-only project

Tags: msbuild, nuget, gitversion

This use case might be a bit off-label, but I'm hoping someone can help me...

For a number of years I've maintained a "library" of MSBuild commands -- in a file we'll call `CommonTasks.targets`, distributed through our internal NuGet server -- that handles various tasks needed by my company's projects. For the last few years I've utilized GitVersion v3 with it, both for generating the library's own NuGet package version numbers as well as utilizing GitVersion's `GetVersion` MSBuild target directly (e.g., when generating a corresponding git tag), to avoid needing to extract the GitVersion-generated version from the dependent project's assembly, post-build.

Previously (with GitVersion v3), all that was required was for my `CommonTasks.targets` file to import the GitVersionTask.targets file located in GitVersion's NuGet package at `\build\dotnet\GitVersionTasks.targets`. This targets file in turn executed the necessary `UsingTask` commands (particularly `GitVersionTask.GetVersion`) which then let me call `<GetVersion ...>` in my own `.targets` file after the import.

With v4, GitVersionTask has introduced a dependency on UtilPack.NuGet.MSBuild (which I gather helps with various NuGet commands). To start with, that meant that I needed to import its `UtilPack.NuGet.MSBuild.props` file, or GitVersionTask wouldn't load at all. However, having done that, I now get unexpected errors attempting to call `GetVersion` from within an MSBuild file. Seemingly, the GetVersion target now attempts to query all my defined NuGet repositories (nuget.org, local caches, our company server, etc.) for the packaged version of my library, and at the end I'm greeted with this error:

```
  MSBUILD : NuGetTaskRunnerFactory error NR0001: [NuGet Error]: Unable to find package CommonTasks with version
 (>= 1.37.0-gitversiontask4-0001) [C:\redacted\CommonTasks\Build.proj]
MSBUILD : NuGetTaskRunnerFactory error NR0001:   - Found 108 version(s) in Source1 [ Nearest version: 1.36.3 ] [C:\redacted\CommonTasks\Build.proj]
MSBUILD : NuGetTaskRunnerFactory error NR0001:   - Found 42 version(s) in Source2 [ Nearest version: 1.36.3 ] [C:\redacted\CommonTasks\Build.proj]
MSBUILD : NuGetTaskRunnerFactory error NR0001:   - Found 0 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [C:\redacted\CommonTasks\Build.proj]
MSBUILD : NuGetTaskRunnerFactory error NR0001:   - Found 0 version(s) in nuget.org [C:\redacted\CommonTasks\Build.proj]
  MSBUILD : Task factory error NMSBT003: Failed to find main package CommonTasks@. [C:\redacted\CommonTasks\Build.proj(47,9): error MSB4175: The task factory "Ut
ilPack.NuGet.MSBuild.NuGetTaskRunnerFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly "C:\redacted\CommonTasks\packages\UtilPack.NuGet.MSBuild.2.7.0\build\\net46\UtilPack.NuGet.MSBuild.dll". Object ref
erence not set to an instance of an object.
```

What I don't get is why it's attempting NuGet retrievals at all, and, even if that's the new default behavior, I don't know a way to disable that, or barring that, I don't know why it's not working. I assume the error must have something to do with this not being a normal .NET project (i.e., with no source code aside from a .targets file, no .csproj file, etc.). But my library is used by many normal .NET projects, which themselves use GitVersionTask to auto-version their assemblies.

For now I've pinned my library to GitVersionTask v3, but would very much like to figure out how to allow it to use v4 as I'd been using v3 previously. I could likely switch to using the GitVersion.CommandLine package instead, and parsing its output, but I ultimately do need these GitVersion-generated versions as MSBuild properties in order to use them as intended. And with dependent projects also using GitVersionTask (not the CLI), it's convenient to be able to use a single package for both.

Is there a way to fix what I'm doing with GitVersionTask v4, or some completely different (perhaps more elegant) way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Can you please add you project file here, at leas tany part that mentions `gitversion`